# Visual problem with new construction home

Tags: first-time-home-buyer

We bought this new construction house. Our final inspection is not until next week, but we went to see the house yesterday and noticed that the light pendants over the floating island in the kitchen are not uniformly apart. It sounds silly, but its so off that it is the first thing that we noticed. We do want to bring this to the builders attention. My question is whether I should email them now or wait until final inspection to let them know? My concern with the latter is that the inspection is too soon to the closing and having them fix it will push the closing out. So, please advise.

Comment: Do it now.  It does not sound silly.  Point out everything!

Comment: Why would you wait?  I think I must be missing something since there seems to be no advantage to waiting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it now. Buidlers can get really backed up and not correct issues in your home for another 2-3 months after the home closes. They have labor turnover. If it's an issue to you, request it to be repaired promptly and get it in writing or a confirmed appointment.

Answer (score 2):

Well either it pushes the closing out or you pay to fix it yourselves.  Many new homes are built with a certain amount of warranties.  Some states require 1, 2, 3, and I have seen even 5 years.  There are warranty issues where something doesn't work or has gone bad and there are some where the house was not built according to contract.

When things go bad this is often easy to enforce.  An outlet stopped working, fix it.  However when you have a light that was misplaced by a few inches or a foot, this often can get hazy and is really hard to enforce after you sign off on the house.  In some or even most cases this would not be considered a new home warranty concern and you would have to go to small claims court to have it fixed and small claims judge may say, you signed off on it.

If you have to have it closed by a certain date, you could sign off on it after the builder signs a list of promises.  They would promise to fix XYZ after closing.  Again this is fine but puts a lot of the risk on you.  What if the builder doesn't do something?  And for most of the issues - what if the builder doesn't do something the way you wanted/thought it would be done?  For instance let's say the builder moves the light 2 feet but causes another issue - is that other issue outlined in the promises?  If not builder could and might charge you for it.  Unless you have experience in construction I would be 100% sure before signing off on a house.  I would do a 10 hour inspection on every nook and cranny on it.

Just note that when an issue is kind of the builder's fault and kind of the new home owner's fault the home owner almost always pays the price.  Your builder has other jobs to do and anything that comes up on your house is costing them money.